# numpy behaves differently on a normal Jupiter notebook and one from a visual studio venv

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-console

I am running a web version of a Jupyter notebook from a course material, and this code cell runs through successfully:

[image]

But when I ran it from a VS CODE virtual environment, I get the below error. Please help with the error.

[image]

Comment: Do you have same python version/env for vs code and the web?

Comment: Please share all code and errors as text, not images.

Comment: I wouldn't stress much about this flawed example, dig_123/ Most likely your web version of Jupyter uses a different version of numpy that doesn't detect the flawed code your course is using. (It is even called **badmatrix** to emphasize that.) From a pedagogical viewpoint, I've seen it said 'don't teach the wrong way' to do something, which looks like it was done here. ([Example](https://blog.acthompson.net/2021/01/does-bad-code-lead-to-good-learning.html).)  From a practical viewpoint, the instructor cannot know when the software might be adjusted to deal with bad code for matrix ...

Comment: <continued> formation up front, like seems to have happened here.

Answer (score 1):

You are not stating what you mean by "web version". But in any case, you very likely have different versions of numpy. You can run

```
import numpy as np
np.__version__
```

in both of your environments to check the version you are using. Then, if you want to have the same version in your local VSCode, simply open the terminal and run

```
pip install numpy==x.y.z
```

Where x.y.z is the version you had in the web version.